# Minimize $a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5 = p^4+q^4+r^4+s^4 = x^3+y^3+z^3 = m^2 + n^2$ with distinct positive integers

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics

> Find the minimum value of the following:
>   $$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5 = p^4+q^4+r^4+s^4 = x^3+y^3+z^3 = m^2 + n^2$$
>   where all numbers are different/distinct positive integers.

I know the answer (see below), but want to confirm the same.

Is there any way to prove following conjecture?

> **Conjecture.** There is always unique way to write down $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}^n$ for any arbitrary value of $n$ such that it gives same value for all values of $n$.

---

`Answer is given below, spoiler alert:`

> $$1^5+2^5+4^5+7^5+9^5 = 3^4+6^4+10^4+16^4 = 17^3+20^3+40^3 = 88^2 + 263^2 = 76913$$

Comment: Is there any way to post answer with hidden text? i.e. with Kind of a spoiler alert?

Comment: @peter : Even under comment? or I need to post it as an answer?

Comment: Ok Thx I instead posted directly in question with spoiler alert

Comment: btw main question is still on, is this the minimum and whether there is any way to prove the conjecture :)

Comment: Looks good - you might want to write something outside of it though so people know that it is a spoiler

Comment: I don't understand the conjecture: for any arbitrary value of $n$ the same value for all values of $n$ ? Could you write down this more clearly, say for $n=3$ ?

Comment: For instance for $n = 3$ we have $1^3+2^3+4^3 = 3^2+8^2 = 73$
for $n =4$ we have $1^4+2^4+8^4+24^4 = 18^3+25^3+68^3 = 120^2+567^2 = 335889$
for n=5 I have already asked the question
Seems like you have such arrangements for all higher values of n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the smallest is

```
76913 squares of: 263  88
76913 cubes of: 40  17  20
76913 fourth powers of: 16  3  6  10
76913 fifth powers of: 9  1  2  4  7
76913
```

the second smallest is

```
1560402 squares of: 1239  159
1560402 cubes of: 101  45  76
1560402 fourth powers of: 35  5  12  14
1560402 fifth powers of: 17  1  6  8  10
1560402
```

Here is another one. It may or may not be the third smallest.

```
2091473 squares of: 1367  472
2091473 cubes of: 122  10  65
2091473 fourth powers of: 32  14  21  30
2091473 fifth powers of: 17  4  8  10  14
    2091473
```

Comment: By computer program?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. BTW have you noticed that there is also a prime number which can be represented like this for different values of n.
For instance for $n = 3$ we have $1^3+2^3+4^3 = 3^2+8^2 = 73$ which is a prime.

For $n = 4$ we have $6^4+8^4+9^4+28^4 =  33^3+34^3+82^3 = 175^2+772^2 = 626609$ again a prime number.

For $n=5$ I have already asked this question where btw $76913$ is also a prime :)
Curious, isn't it?

Comment: BTW $2091473$ is also a prime :)

Comment: @user3137471 I found 2091473 by asking for primes, which is the reason I do not know whether some composite number might be the genuine third smallest. 1560402 is 18 times a large prime. Also, any hope of discussing your main conjecture needs restrictions; for any exponent $k,$ the numbers expressible by your rules are density zero, like the primes.

Comment: can you share code for the same.  I am intrigued  that you asked for primes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include "form.h"

using namespace std;


int is_2_different_positive_2th_powers(mpz_class n)
{
  int fail = 1;
  for(mpz_class z = 1; fail && z * z < n; ++z){
    if(  mp_SquareQ(n - z * z )  )
    {
      mpz_class y =  mp_Sqrt(n - z * z );
      if ( y >= 1 && y != z   )
      { 
        fail = 0;
       // cout << n << " squares of: " << y << "  " << z << endl; 
      }
    }
  }
  return !fail;
}

int is_3_different_positive_3th_powers(mpz_class n)
{
  int fail = 1;
  for(mpz_class z = 2; fail && z * z * z < n; ++z){
  for(mpz_class y = 1; fail && y < z && y * y * y + z * z * z < n; ++y){
    mpz_class xxx = n - (y * y * y + z * z * z) ;
    if (mp_CubeQ( xxx) )
    {
       mpz_class x = mp_Cube_Root(xxx);
       if ( x > 0 && x != y && x != z)
       { 
        fail = 0;
       // cout << n << " cubes of: " << x << "  " << y << "  " << z << endl; 
      } 
    }

  }}
  return !fail;
}

int is_4_different_positive_4th_powers(mpz_class n)
{
  int fail = 1;
  for(mpz_class z = 3; fail && z * z * z * z < n; ++z){
  for(mpz_class y = 2; fail && y < z && y * y * y * y + z * z * z * z < n; ++y){
  for(mpz_class x = 1; fail && x < y && x * x * x * x + y * y * y * y + z * z * z * z < n; ++x){
     mpz_class wwww = n - (  x * x * x * x + y * y * y * y + z * z * z * z );
     if(  mp_Fourth_Power_Q(wwww ))
     {
       mpz_class w = mp_Fourth_Root(wwww);
       if( w > 0 && w != x && w != y && w != z)
      { 
        fail = 0;
       // cout << n << " fourth powers of: " <<  w << "  " << x << "  " << y << "  " << z << endl; 
      } 


     }
  }}}
  return !fail;
}



int is_5_different_positive_5th_powers(mpz_class n)
{
  int fail = 1;
  for(mpz_class z = 4; fail && to_power_5(z) < n; ++z){
  for(mpz_class y = 3; fail && y < z && to_power_5(y) + to_power_5(z) < n; ++y){
  for(mpz_class x = 2; fail && x < y && to_power_5(x) + to_power_5(y) + to_power_5(z) < n; ++x){
  for(mpz_class w = 1; fail && w < x &&  to_power_5(w) + to_power_5(x) + to_power_5(y) + to_power_5(z) < n; ++w){
     mpz_class vvvvv = n - (  to_power_5(w) + to_power_5(x) + to_power_5(y) + to_power_5(z) );
     if(  mp_Fifth_Power_Q(vvvvv))
     {
       mpz_class v =  mp_Fifth_Root(vvvvv);
       if( v > 0 && v != w && v != x && v != y && v != z) 
       { 
        fail = 0;
       // cout << n << " fifth powers of: " <<  v << "  " << w << "  " << x << "  " << y << "  " << z << endl; 
      } 


     }
  }}}}
  return !fail;
}


int is_6_different_positive_6th_powers(mpz_class n)
{
  int fail = 1;
  for(mpz_class z = 5; fail && to_power_6(z) < n; ++z){
  for(mpz_class y = 4; fail && y < z && to_power_6(y) + to_power_6(z) < n; ++y){
  for(mpz_class x = 3; fail && x < y && to_power_6(x) + to_power_6(y) + to_power_6(z) < n; ++x){
  for(mpz_class w = 2; fail && w < x &&  to_power_6(w) + to_power_6(x) + to_power_6(y) + to_power_6(z) < n; ++w){
  for(mpz_class v = 1; fail && v < w &&  to_power_6(v) + to_power_6(w) + to_power_6(x) + to_power_6(y) + to_power_6(z) < n; ++w){
     mpz_class uuuuuu = n - (  to_power_6(v) + to_power_6(w) + to_power_6(x) + to_power_6(y) + to_power_6(z)  );
     if(  mp_Sixth_Power_Q( uuuuuu))
     {
       mpz_class u =  mp_Sixth_Root(uuuuuu);
       if( u > 0 && u != v && u != w && u != x && u != y && u != z) 
       { 
        fail = 0;
     //   cout << n << " sixth powers of: " <<   u << "  " << v << "  " << w << "  " << x << "  " << y << "  " << z << endl; 
      } 


     }
  }}}}}
  return !fail;
}




int main()
{
   for(mpz_class p = 1; p <= 1000000000; p += 4 ){
   if( p % 10000 == 1 ) cerr << p << endl;
     if (  mp_PrimeQ(p) &&   is_2_different_positive_2th_powers(p) && is_3_different_positive_3th_powers(p) && is_4_different_positive_4th_powers(p)  && is_5_different_positive_5th_powers(p)  && is_6_different_positive_6th_powers(p)) cout << "    " << p << endl;
   }


    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;


const int LARGEINT = 2147483647  ;
const int BILLION  = 1000000000  ;
const double my_pi = 4 * atan(1.0);

//  form.h      



int mp_PrimeQ( mpz_class  i)
{
  if ( i <= 0 ) return 0;
  else if ( i == 1 ) return 1;
  else return  mpz_probab_prime_p( i.get_mpz_t() , 10 );
} // mp_PrimeQ


int  mp_SquareQ( mpz_class  w)
{
  if (w < 0) return 0;
  else if (w < 2) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class squirt;
    mpz_sqrt( squirt.get_mpz_t(), w.get_mpz_t()  );
    return (w ==  squirt * squirt);
  }  // else w >= 2;
}

mpz_class mp_Sqrt( mpz_class  w)
{
  if (w <= 0) return 0;
  else if (w < 2) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class squirt;
    mpz_sqrt( squirt.get_mpz_t(), w.get_mpz_t()  );
    return  squirt ;
  }  // else w >= 2;
}



int  mp_CubeQ( mpz_class  w)
{
  mpz_class temp = w;
  if (temp < 0) temp *= -1;
  if (temp < 2) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class root;
    mpz_root( root.get_mpz_t(), temp.get_mpz_t(), 3  );
  //  cout << " root " << root <<  "  temp " << temp << endl;
    return (temp ==  root * root * root);
  }  // else w >= 2;
}

mpz_class mp_Cube_Root( mpz_class  w)
{
   mpz_class temp = w;
  if (temp < 0) temp *= -1;
  if( temp == 0) return 0;
  else  if (temp < 2) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class root;
    mpz_root( root.get_mpz_t(), temp.get_mpz_t(), 3  );
  //  cout << " root " << root <<  "  temp " << temp << endl;
    return  root;
  }  // else w >= 2; 
}

mpz_class mp_Fourth_Root( mpz_class  w)
{
   mpz_class temp = w;
  if (temp < 0) temp *= -1;
  if( temp == 0) return 0;
  else  if (temp <= 15) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class root;
    mpz_root( root.get_mpz_t(), temp.get_mpz_t(), 4  );
  //  cout << " root " << root <<  "  temp " << temp << endl;
    return  root;
  }  // else w >= 2; 
}


int  mp_Fourth_Power_Q( mpz_class  w)
{
  mpz_class temp = w;
  mpz_class root = mp_Fourth_Root( w);
  return root * root * root * root == w;
}

mpz_class mp_Fifth_Root( mpz_class  w)
{
   mpz_class temp = w;
  if (temp < 0) temp *= -1;
  if( temp == 0) return 0;
  else  if (temp <= 31) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class root;
    mpz_root( root.get_mpz_t(), temp.get_mpz_t(), 5  );
  //  cout << " root " << root <<  "  temp " << temp << endl;
    return  root;
  }  // else w >= 2; 
}


int  mp_Fifth_Power_Q( mpz_class  w)
{
  mpz_class temp = w;
  mpz_class root = mp_Fifth_Root( w);
  return root * root * root * root * root == w;
}


mpz_class to_power_5( mpz_class w)
{
  return w * w * w * w * w;
}


//    6     
mpz_class mp_Sixth_Root( mpz_class  w)
{
   mpz_class temp = w;
  if (temp < 0) temp *= -1;
  if( temp == 0) return 0;
  else  if (temp <= 63) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class root;
    mpz_root( root.get_mpz_t(), temp.get_mpz_t(), 6  );
  //  cout << " root " << root <<  "  temp " << temp << endl;
    return  root;
  }  // else w >= 2; 
}


int  mp_Sixth_Power_Q( mpz_class  w)
{
  mpz_class temp = w;
  mpz_class root = mp_Sixth_Root( w);
  return root * root * root * root * root * root == w;
}


mpz_class to_power_6( mpz_class w)
{
  return w * w * w * w * w * w;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it turns out that the right way to do this is one multiple loop to produce sums of the highest exponent under consideration, then test those as sums of distinct powers with the lower exponents. The point is that, as the exponent increases, the sums get scarcer and scarcer, so it is a gigantic waste to test from the bottom up. Here are all those that work up to exponent $5$ up to 10,000,000. Note that they are not in increasing order, they are instead in order of the largest $x_5$ in $n = x_1^5 + ... + x_5^5$

```
Sat May 21 10:04:16 PDT 2016
76913 =  76913    count:  1
1560402 =  2 3^2 86689    count:  2
1792449 =  3^4 22129    count:  3
2091473 =  2091473    count:  4
3449969 =  3449969    count:  5
3980017 =  3980017    count:  6
5542594 =  2 2771297    count:  7
8603153 =  13 41 16141    count:  8
7175969 =  43^2 3881    count:  9
8464113 =  3^2 7^2 17 1129    count:  10 
7902369 =  3^2 878041    count:  11
7502993 =  181 41453    count:  12
7949041 =  641 12401    count:  13
9453634 =  2 4726817    count:  14
9467074 =  2 4733537    count:  15
8907634 =  2 4453817    count:  16
9044993 =  9044993    count:  17
9801793 =  9801793    count:  18
Sat May 21 10:55:06 PDT 2016
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Sordid:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ sort -n five.txt
76913 =  76913    count:  1
1560402 =  2 3^2 86689    count:  2
1792449 =  3^4 22129    count:  3
2091473 =  2091473    count:  4
3449969 =  3449969    count:  5
3980017 =  3980017    count:  6
5542594 =  2 2771297    count:  7
7175969 =  43^2 3881    count:  9
7502993 =  181 41453    count:  12
7902369 =  3^2 878041    count:  11
7949041 =  641 12401    count:  13
8464113 =  3^2 7^2 17 1129    count:  10 
8603153 =  13 41 16141    count:  8
8907634 =  2 4453817    count:  16
9044993 =  9044993    count:  17
9453634 =  2 4726817    count:  14
9467074 =  2 4733537    count:  15
9801793 =  9801793    count:  18
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for a day or two to see if anyone here has any analytical  approach to share, after that I will accept your main answer.

Comment: @user3137471 what this means is that we can probably increase the exponent to 6. Don't see how to even begin with your conjecture for arbitrary largest exponent.

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling that it will work for n=6 and beyond

Comment: @user3137471 I am using the method in this answer to check for $n=6,$ with the largest variable up to 25. It took about 15 hours to do 24, so I guess it won't finish until tomorrow. The result, yes or no, will be definitive for $n$ up to $25^6$ which is 244,140,625.

Comment: Thanks, will look forward for the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Will Jagy for sharing the code.
I had used following VBA code in excel 

`Sub Power5()
For u = 1 To 10
    For v = u + 1 To 10
        For w = v + 1 To 10
            For x = w + 1 To 10
                For y = x + 1 To 10
                    mysum = u ^ 5 + v ^ 5 + w ^ 5 + x ^ 5 + y ^ 5
                    For p = 1 To 100
                        For q = p + 1 To 100
                            For r = q + 1 To 100
                                For s = r + 1 To 100
                                    If p ^ 4 + q ^ 4 + r ^ 4 + s ^ 4 = mysum Then
                                        For i = 1 To 100
                                            For j = i + 1 To 100
                                                For k = j + 1 To 100
                                                    If i ^ 3 + j ^ 3 + k ^ 3 = mysum Then
                                                        For a = 1 To 1000
                                                            For b = a + 1 To 1000
                                                                If a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = mysum Then
                                                                    n = n + 1: Cells(n, 1) = u & "| " & v & "| " & w & "| " & x & "| " & y & "<|> " & p & "| " & q & "| " & r & "| " & s & "<|> " & i & "| " & j & "| " & k & "<|> " & a & "| " & b
                                                                    GoTo Mynext
                                                                End If
                                                            Next
                                                        Next
                                                    End If
                                                Next
                                            Next
                                        Next
                                    End If
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
Mynext:
    Next
Next`

End Sub